# How to launch maximised window of Safari Browser in Nightwatch

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js, safaridriver

Nightwatch Configuration file:

```
"globals_path":"./nightwatch/global.js",
"detailed_output":true,
"disable_colors":false,
"output_folder":"./tests_output",
"webdriver":{
   "start_process":true
},
"selenium":{
   "start_process":true,
   "port":4444,
   "host":"localhost",
   "server_path":"./node_modules/selenium-server-standalone-jar/jar/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar",
   "log_path":"",
   "version2":true,
   "cli_args":{
      "webdriver.gecko.driver":"./node_modules/geckodriver/bin/geckodriver",
      "webdriver.chrome.driver":"./node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver",
      "webdriver.safari.driver":"/usr/bin/safaridriver"
   }
},
"test_settings":{
   "default":{
      "launch_url":"https://www.google.com",
      "silent":true,
      "skip_testcases_on_fail":false,
      "end_session_on_fail":false,
      "screenshots":{
         "enabled":true,
         "path":"./screenshots"
      },
      "webdriver":{
         "start_process":true,
         "server_path":"/usr/bin/safaridriver",
         "port":0,
         "cli_args":[
            "--verbose"
         ]
      },
      "desiredCapabilities":{
         "browserName":"Safari",
         "javascriptEnabled":true,
         "acceptSslCerts":true,
         "safari.options":{
            "excludeSwitches":[
               "enable-automation"
            ],
            "args":[
               "start-maximized",
               "window-size=1980,1024",
               "--disable-web-security",
               "--disable-notifications",
               "--private"
            ]
         }
      }
   },
```

Hi,
The above code is the `Nightwatch.js` file with the configuration of `desiredCapalibities` and `safaridriver`. I have mentioned the `start-maximized` command and also, set the window size and my window size is (1280X800) but still, it is not opening in the maximized window. I have checked the Safari browser `Allow Remote Automation` option and also check the `Show Developer menu in menu bar` under the preferences section of Safari but no option is working.

Can you please suggest any other option or set up I need for the Safari browser?

Can anybody tell me how I can launch safaridriver in a new and maximized window?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set `browser.maximizeWindow();` in the `beforeEach` hook in global configuration file